# Intuitively recognise eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I recognise eigenvalues without calculation?

[image]

Comment: The question is not to find them without calculation, but to find them without using a matrix representation. Instead, write out what it *means* to be an eigenvalue/eigenvector of one of these transformation. For example, for the second one: suppose $A$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. This means $\lambda A = A^T$. What does this imply about $\lambda$ and $A$? Let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: ah yes that makes sense, I got the (correct) answer for part b. Could you please give me a hint for part a or c? Thanks

Comment: For a), consider what happens to a generic vector $v$ upon applying $P$ once and then once more. This gives you a simple relation for $P$ which will make the eigenvalue problem $Pv=\lambda v$ straightforward. For c) write out the eigenvalue problem and note that it's equivalent to an ODE.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a relatively short answer to each of the questions. Be sure to check whether everything is clear; for me these answers would be sufficient, but your teacher might want a more worked out solution, which you should be able to provide.

a) The vectors which lie in the plane you're projecting on, are send to themselves. Thus, there is a two-dimensional eigenspace with eigenvalue $1$, consisting of the vectors in the given plane. On the other hand, the vector $(3, 1, -2)$, which is orthogonal to the plane, is send to $0$ under the given projection (do you see why?). Hence, it is a vector with eigenvalue $0$. Since we can find a two-dimensional eigenspace with eigenvalue $1$ and a third eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$, these are the only eigenvectors (do you see why there can't be more?)

b) If $A$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$
A = \lambda A^T = \lambda^2 (A^T)^T = \lambda^2 A 
$$
such that $\lambda^2 = 1$ and thus $\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda = -1$. (This simple approach was pointed out to me by *Semiclassical*.) In the first case, the eigenspace consists exactly of the three-dimensional subspace of symmetric matrices. Find an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = -1$ yourself.

c) Since $2$ is always a root of $R(p)$, $p$ can only be an eigenvector if $2$ is a root of $p$ or $\lambda = 0$. Check yourself that there is a one-dimensional eigenspace belonging to $\lambda = 0$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then an eigenvector $p$ must be of the form $(x-2)(ax + b)$. One can then easily calculate that this is an eigenvector if and only if $b = -2a$. (do this!)

Comment: Another approach to c) is to note that the eigenvalue problem $(x-2)p'(x)=\lambda p(x)$ is an ODE with general solution $p(x)=A(x-2)^\lambda$ with $A$ the constant of integration. All that remains is to use the fact that $p(x)$ should be an element of $\mathcal{P}_2$.

Comment: Also, for one b) has $$Q(A)=A^T=\lambda A\implies A=\lambda A^T=\lambda^2 A\implies \lambda=\pm 1$$ without dropping into matrix form.

Comment: That is indeed an improvement. I will change this.